# в чем разница между папками src и dist

Tags: html, css

что хранится в src, а что в dist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src/` содержит исходный код и является необработанным кодом до минимизации или конкатенации или какой-либо другой компиляции - используется для чтения/редактирования кода.

`dist/` содержит распределение и является версией миниатюрной/конкатенированной, фактически используемой на проде.